# Fitting a Poisson distribution from missing observations

Tags: binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution, missing-data, count-data, negative-binomial-distribution

I am interested in fitting a Poisson/negative binomial distribution to estimate the number of times a phenomenon happens within a period, let's just say 10 years. I can count the events from monthly reports, but unfortunately, there are reports missing. So for one sample, I might have 120 observational slots, but for some others I might have 30. The event can happen if it is not observed.

The missing slots pattern is random (ie not correlated between samples), and it can result in anything from a nearly complete observational record to a very decimated one.

How can I cope with this?

Comment: If there is an underlying  Poisson process or a Negative Binomial Lévy process, the distribution of the number of events within a period can be related to the 
effective duration which may be known, possibly with error. For instance, if you  know that within a month the process was only observed during 20 days, this can
be used in a GLM with appropriate link.

Comment: @Yves We assume that the maximum temporal resolution is a month. The day of month when the event happens is of no consequence here.

Comment: So why not simply omit the missing observations in the estimation e.g., using Maximum Likelihood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your problem is one where you have a fixed rate at which the event happens (after adjusting for covariates), but one unit you observe say 10 years while another for only 1 year.  This is a fairly standard problem for this type of model, and the "offset" or an "exposure" is designed for that problem. Once you know those keyword, it is easy to find more about that in any textbook dealing with count data. As a textbook I like http://www.stata.com/bookstore/regression-models-categorical-dependent-variables

Answer (score 0):

You need to think more about the data and provide more information so we can help:

1. is the missing pattern consistent in different time slot?

From the information you provided, each time slot has random missing pattern, I assume you mean the missingness of a certain slot will not correlate with other time slots.

1. what is the fraction of missing? if this fraction is small enough, you may consider throw them out or just fill in the mean value.

From your information, one way I can think of is to estimate Poisson/negative binomial parameters from completes observations. e.g. X_ij where i means sample and j means time points. You first select non-missing X_ij, then the mean of these non-missing X_ij can be thought as an estimator under the Poisson distribution.

Note: this naive method assumes random missingness and independence between time slots. For violations of these assumptions, you will need advanced techniques (i.e. imputation + time series).

Comment: Added some more detail, hope that helps

Comment: Welcome to the site, @zhanxw. At present this is actually a comment asking for more info, not an answer. Since the OP has provided more info, would you expand this into a proper answer? You could also make it into a real answer by explaining how this information is needed to address the situation. Note that, if this cannot be turned into an actual answer, it may need to be deleted. Since you're new here, you might want to read our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq), which discusses things like this.

Answer (score 0):

What it sound like you have is censored data, specifically right censored data. The events occurred, but they were not observed. [Censoring (statistics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censoring_%28statistics%29)

If you are using R the `fitdistrplus` package that has exactly what you need. It has the function `fitdistcens` which can fit data with right, left and interval censoring.